# Replace non-unique occurences with sed or other command

Tags: replace, sed

my first post here and beginner level. Is there a way I can solve this problem with sed (or any other means)? I want to manipulate a newly created file daily and replace some IP and port occurences.

1) I want to replace the first occurence of "5027,5028" with A3 and the second with A4.
2) I want to replace the first occurence of "5026" with A1 and the second with A2.

PS. I have tried to simplify the example and left the preceeding lines with version="y" or version="x" that could be of help to distinguish the occurences from eachother. (The first x and y version pair is a primary connection and the other two the secondary connection).

**Input file:**

```
version="x"
commaSeparatedList="5027,5028"`
version="y"
commaSeparatedList="5026"
version="x"
commaSeparatedList="5027,5028"
version="y"
commaSeparatedList="5026"
```

**Edited file:**

```
version="1.4.1-12"
commaSeparatedList="A3"
version="1.3.0"
commaSeparatedList="A1"
version="1.4.1-12"
commaSeparatedList="A4"
version="1.3.0"
commaSeparatedList="A2"
```

Sorry, I had some editing horror for a few minutes. Hope it looks easier to understand now. I am basically receiving this file on a system that is deployed nightly and I want to edit this file using a cron job before it starts to make sure a connection works.

Comment: two questions: 1) is it possible duplicated numbers in same line? how to deal with if ture. 2), what if the 3rd, 4th... 5026 comes... keep `A2`? or it won't happen?

Comment: and 3rd question, why input is y-y-x-y, output is x-y-x-y?

Answer (score 2):

Do not bother trying to use `sed` for this.  It can be done, but `sed` is the wrong tool.

Use `awk` instead.  To  replace the first occurrence of "5027,5028" with A3 and the second with A4.

```
awk '/5027,5028/ && count < 2 { if( count ++ ) repl="A4"; else repl="A3";
    sub( "5027,5028", repl)} 1' input
```

The second replacement is left as an exercise.  It is basically the same thing, and you can either run awk twice or just add additional clauses the above.

To overwrite the original file, use shell redirections:

```
awk ... input > tmpfile && mv tmpfile input
```

Comment: Much appreciated, will test it out very soon!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU Sed):

```
sed '1,/5027,5028/s/5027,5028/A3/;s/5027,5028/A4/;1,/5026/s/5026/A1/;s/5026/A2/' file
```